# Setting Button for Live Wallpapers Doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-settings

When I click **Settings...** in my live wallpaper I get

> Unfortunately, Live Wallpaper Picker has stopped

This is my wallpaper XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/fish1" 
android:description="@string/wallpaper_description" 
android:settingsActivity="com.example.fishwall.MainSettings"/>
```

And this this the Settings java file

```
public class MainSettings extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

Comment: the xml file name is prefs?

Comment: yes it's the PreferenceScreen XML file

Answer (score 0):

you need to export your Settings activity. Without exporting it it is unavailable for the Wallpaper Selector.
Something like this in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainSettings"
        android:exported="true"/>
```